# Linked Server - MSDTC no tiene habilitado el soporte para transacciones remotas, pero si hay conexión (responde a SELECT) al servidor remoto

Tags: sql, sql-server, transacciones

Tengo 2 servidores [SQL-Server] 2016,

- A - que tiene la BD a procesar
- B - que es el servidor remoto, que se conectará a A en modo [Linked-Server]

Seguí entre otras ayudas que encontré, las siguientes:

- [How do I enable MSDTC on SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694/how-do-i-enable-msdtc-on-sql-server)
- [Configure MSDTC on SQL Server and adapter client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/configure-msdtc-on-sql-server-and-adapter-client)
- [Configure Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)](https://support.resolver.com/hc/en-ca/articles/207161116-Configure-Microsoft-Distributed-Transaction-Coordinator-MSDTC-)

Entonces si es posible,

- Ya puedo realizar la conexión a mi servidor remoto, viendo los objetos desde el explorador
- Me es posible realizar Select's obteniendo los resultados

No es posible:

- Ejecutar transacciones como insertar en tablas

Error:

```
(0 rows affected)
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "NombreLinkedServer" returned message "El administrador de transacción ha deshabilitado su soporte para transacciones de red o remotas.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "NombreLinkedServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Pruebas:

- El uso real será a través de VPN en una ubicación diferente, pero también hice pruebas en red local.
- Firewall desactivado para evitar que sea tema de ésto.
- Puerto default 1433 para descartar.
- Todas las opciones configuradas y habilitadas en la configuración del MSDTC como se muestra en la imagen adjunta al final.
- El reinicio del servidor A completo para descartar que sea un tema de la un mal inicio de los servicios.
- Conexión en red local con modo SQL SERVER y no con ODBC, para descartar que fuera un tema de driver.

[image: Configuración de seguridad de MSDTC]